# Error BC30002: Type 'MQQueueManager' is not defined

Tags: ibm-mq, .net-framework-version

We have .Net Framework 4.0 console app which communicate with IBM MQ 7.0.1 via "amqmdnet" and "amqmdxcs" dlls. We need to upgrade to IBM MQ to 9.3.4.

We changed the reference of "amqmdnet" and "amqmdxcs" dlls to IBM MQ 9.3.4 to the console app as well we upgraded .Net framework from 4 to 4.7.1. While compiling we are getting the error "BC30002: Type 'MQQueueManager' is not defined."

Comment: Show your code showing the reference to `MQQueueManager`.

Answer (score 1):

***> We need to upgrade to IBM MQ to 9.3.4.***

This is one of those RTM (Read The Manual) times.

In the MQ Knowledge Center, you need to read the "[Hardware and software requirements on Windows systems](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=windows-hardware-software-requirements-systems)" section. Scroll down to the "[Requirements for IBM MQ classes for .NET](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=windows-hardware-software-requirements-systems#q008450___netcore__title__1)" sub-section and for v9.3.1 (or higher), it says:

> From IBM MQ 9.3.1, for .NET 6 IBM MQ client libraries, that is
> libraries built using .NET 6 as the target framework, .NET 6 is a
> prerequisite.

***> we upgraded .Net framework from 4 to 4.7.1.***

So, your problem is that you are not using the correct release of .NET for IBM MQ v9.3.4.0.